# What does a 'reading' mean?

Tags: meaning

Many guides and secondary text are called 'readings' e.g. Oxford Readings in Philosophy. What does it mean? Does this 'reading' specifically refer to a particular interpretations of the original texts that these books are based on e.g. readings of Nietzche?

Comment: Lectures, essays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'readings' here is a concise way of saying "*things one ought to read on this subject to be well-informed*". These kinds of books are meant to give general background material on a particular topic area for students and professionals. Usually they contain important or seminal works that establish the worldview of the discipline; as opposed to cutting edge research that defines the frontiers of the discipline, which would more normally be found in journals or other academic sources.